# SilverStripe 3.1 loop associative array

Tags: arrays, foreach, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 I have a function that loops through an array and outputs its contents.

The output it gives me is:

> Layout: John
>
> Strategy: John
>
> Management: Martin

In this example John has more than one job.

I would like to group the jobs if a person has more than one job.

This is my desired Output:

> Layout and Strategy: John
>
> Management: Martin

```
//$InfoFieldArray = array('Layout' => 'John', 'Strategy' => 'John', 'Management' => 'Martin');

public function createInfoFields($InfoFieldArray){ 

    $Info = ArrayList::create();
    foreach($InfoFieldArray as $key => $value ){
        $fields = new ArrayData(array('FieldName' => $key, 'Value' => $value));
        $Info->push($fields);
    }   
    return $Info;
}
```

How do I alter my function to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution to that is by restructuring the data before adding it to the [`ArrayList`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ArrayList.html).

```
public function createInfoFields($InfoFieldArray)
{
    $info = array();

    foreach ($InfoFieldArray as $job => $person)
    {
        if (!isset($info[$person]))
        {
            $info[$person] = array();
        }

        $info[$person][] = $job;
    }

    $result = ArrayList::create();
    foreach ($info as $person => $jobs)
    {
        $fields = new ArrayData(array('FieldName' => implode(' and ', $jobs), 'Value' => $person));
        $result->push($fields);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

What I have done is go over the array of jobs and the person assigned and flipped it the other way around, so I have an array of people with a list of jobs. This allows me to then just call [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP, joining the various jobs by the word `and`.

There are some potential drawbacks, if there are two people named "John", they will be treated as one as I am using the name as the array key.

Also, if there are three jobs for a person, it will list it like "Layout and Strategy and Management". To avoid that, we need to modify the second foreach loop in my code to something like this:

```
    foreach ($info as $person => $jobs)
    {
        $jobString = null;

        if (count($jobs) > 1)
        {
            $jobString = implode(', ', array_slice($jobs, 0, -1)) . ' and ' . array_pop($jobs);
        }
        else
        {
            $jobString = $jobs[0];
        }

        $fields = new ArrayData(array('FieldName' => $jobString, 'Value' => $person));
        $result->push($fields);
    }
```

When there is more than 1 job for a person, we want to implode (glue together) the array pieces for the `$jobs` array however we don't want the last element at this point. Once array is glued together, we append with with `and` along with the last item.

Comment: Turnerj ! / Thanks for detailed explanation. Works as desired. Cant vote up / need more reputation. Sepp.

Comment: Glad it worked like you wanted. If you can't upvote yet, you should still be able to accept the answer if it has helped you (the tick mark below the up/down arrows). :)